# Integrate adobe flex charts with Jaspersoft ireports

Tags: apache-flex, jasper-reports, ireport

Can we integrate adobe flex charts with Jaspersoft ireports.

Comment: This question is too vague to be answered.  How do you intend to integrate?  What do you intend on exporting to?  The answer is probably no since it doesn't look like you can't embed plugin based objects into a Jasper report.  You may be able to use the other BI software as a back-end to a flex developed charting solution that is interactive, but from glancing through info about Jasper it looks like it's mainly meant for static output.

Comment: thanks shaun for replying i just wanted to know if there is any plugin to integrate both

Comment: hmm okay sounds like you need someone more familiar with jasper you may want to consider contacting them directly to see if the Jasper team can give you some direction.  Sorry I don't have a good solution, best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

For sure you can integrate JasperReports with Flex. We did it. They have released a viewer component but it needs to be slightly modified in order to work with the most recent version of JasperReports.